# Conditionally sample unique IDs on column value = 1 and first date condition

Tags: r, random, dplyr

**Background**

I've got a dataset `d`:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","b","b", "c","c"),
                event = c(0,1,0,0,1,1),
                event_date = as.Date(c("2011-01-01","2012-08-21","2011-12-23","2011-12-31","2013-03-14","2015-07-12")),
                entry_date = as.Date(c("2009-01-01","2009-01-01","2011-09-12","2011-09-12","2005-03-01","2005-03-01")),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

It looks like this:

[image: current]

As you can see, it's got 3 `ID`'s in it, an indicator of whether they had the `event`, a date for that event, and a date for when they entered the dataset.

**The Problem**

I'd like to do some sampling of `ID`'s in the dataset. Specifically, I'd like to sample all the rows of any distinct `ID` who meet the following two conditions:

1. Has *any* `event`=1
2. The date of their first (chronologically earliest) `event_date` row is greater than 365 days but less than 1095 days (3 years) from their `entry_date`.

**Desired result**

If you look at each of the 3 `ID`'s, you'll see that only `ID`= **a** meets both of these criteria: this person has an `event=1` in their second event record, and the date of their first event record is between 1 and 3 years from their `entry_date` (2011-01-01 is exactly two years from their entry date).

So, I'd like a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

**What I've tried**

I'm halfway there: I've managed to get the code to meet my first criterion, but not the second. Have a look:

```
d_esired <- subset(d, ID %in% sample(unique(ID[event == 1]), 1))
```

How can I add the second condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using data.table we can identify those IDs, then subset

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)

d[ID %in% 
  (d[, any(event==1 & any(event_date>(365+entry_date) & event_date<(1095+entry_date))), by=ID][V1==TRUE, ID])]
```

The `any(event_date>(365+entry_date)` tests for valid dates in any row (event can be 0 or 1), and `any(event==1 & ...)` tests whether that occurred and whether an event occurred at any point. That is used to return a vector of ID values. The `%in%` operator then tests whether IDs in `d` are in that vector.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This works for this example, no doubt, though I'm gonna try it on my "real" dataset right now to make sure it transposes nicely onto reality. Question: what is `[V1==TRUE, ID]` doing at the end there? I think I follow the code otherwise.

Comment: That's getting the IDs where the conditions are true from this (run just this bit to see what it returns) `d[, any(event==1 & any(event_date>(365+entry_date) & event_date<(1095+entry_date))), by=ID]` it's a data.table of logical value per ID from that set of logical operations. The second set of square braces is simply "chaining" data.table operations. (If this answers the question please accept the answer)

Comment: Data.table works off a notation of `dt[i,j,by]` which can be endlessly chained to `dt[i,j,by][i,j,by][i,j,by]...` - `i` is the actions on rows like sorting or subsetting, `j` is the operations on columns, and `by` is a grouping for `j` operations. So the `j` in this case is, are there any obs. where event =1 and any obs. where event date is valid? Then asking that question per ID.

Comment: I think I get it, but what's `V1` specifically? (Answer marked btw)

Comment: V1 is just the name of variable R generated in those logical operations- I didn't provide a name so it made one itself